# Dsum function not working with Text field

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've tried just about everything i can think of on why i would get this error, but i have had no luck. I wrote a similar code that references that same table with numerical values that works fine, but when searching for text it has problems. The error code says the missing operator lies here: `[ExpendetureStore] = 'Lowe's`

```
TotalCostTextBox = DSum("[ExpendetureCost]", "ProjectExpendetures", "[ExpendetureStore] = '" & Me.StoreNameCombo & "'")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Lowe's` has an apostrophe in its name. Access query engine is reading that apostrophe as a special character (text delimiter) in the compiled search string. If your data includes apostrophes, one way to deal with is to 'escape' the character - double it in the data with Replace() function. This forces Access to treat the character as normal text.

`TotalCostTextBox = DSum("[ExpendetureCost]", "ProjectExpendetures", "[ExpendetureStore] = '" & Replace(Me.StoreNameCombo, "'", "''") & "'")`

The same will happen with quote marks and are more challenging to deal with. Note the escaping of quote between quotes.
`Replace("somevalue", """", """" & """")`
Or may be easier to understand using Chr() function.
`Replace("somevalue", Chr(34), Chr(34) & Chr(34))`

Side note: Expendeture is a misspelling of Expenditure.

Comment: Ah, now that you say that it makes perfect sense. Works great now, thank you very much!

Comment: Sure, I'd be glad to, but i have't found where to do this. I've pulled quite a bit of code off this site, but i've never posted anything before.